# bigquery bq load- cannot determine table described

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load up a very basic table: cookie:string,campaign_id:integer,point_type:integer.

Here is the file I'm using: http://pastie.org/private/xswuhkotlfxmykozrzws5a

However when i run:  `bq load -F '^' myset.my_test myfile_15.txt cookie:string,campaign_id:integer,point_type:integer` it reports "BigQuery error in load operation: Cannot determine table described by myset.my_test".

However I can upload the same file and schema via the web browser tool and it loads fine.  Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identical command works for me. The error is in parsing the table name, which before it sends any commands to the bigquery service. Can you verify there are no stray unicode chars in your command?

A couple of things to try:

1. Do you have a default project set in your ~/.bigqueryrc file? If not, you might need to prepend the project id to the table name i.e  `bq load -F '^' projectid:myset.my_test ...`. If you don't know which project id to use, you can run `bq ls -p` to get a list of projects you have access to.
2. The table parsing code is shared among commands, so you could try a simpler command: `bq show myset.my_test`. This should give the error "Not found" (since you haven't created the table yet). If that doesn't work either, try just `bq show myset` to lookup just the 
   dataset.
3. If bq show works, you could try a simpler load command line -- such as `bq load myset.my_test myfile_15.txt foo:string`. This may fail because the schema doesn't match, but if you can get beyond the parsing stage it is a sign that something is working.

Comment: Yep this was the problem, was trying to post this but it seems stackoverflow doesn't want you to submit an answer to your own question within a certain time period.  The issue was I didn't have a project set as my default.  Thank you!

Comment: @Daum it works!!!
I also faced the exact problem and applied the same as you said.